# Как правильно указать xsl:for-each select

Tags: xsl

Всем привет!
Не получается правильно указать select в тэге xsl:for-each.  Он должен указывать на xsl:variable.
Код .xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:search="_" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template name="updateAllFields">
        <xsl:for-each select="What should be here?">
        alert('OK');
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    

    <!-- Fields for this screen -->
    <xsl:variable name="someItems">
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <Something1 ... />
        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <Something2 ... />

        <Something3 ... />

    </xsl:variable>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Что нужно указать в аттрибуте select?
Я перепробовал множество вариантов, но ни один не сработал и сообщение ОК не вывелось. Если я правильно понимаю это потому что цикл не содержит никаких данных.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсобщества обновил